# Limit geom_* to calendR dimensions

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a side-project, I need to print out a monthly calendar that has daily splits for each day.  This is a drawing project more than a data science project, but seems like there should be an easy solution in ggplot2.

```
# package ----------

library(ggplot2)
library(calendR)
library(glue)

# Develop Monthly Schedule -------------

this_year <- 2023

custom_cal <- calendR(year= this_year,
        month = 10,
        title = glue("October {this_year}"),
        text.size = 2.5,
        margin = .25,
        weeknames = c("Mo", "Tu",  # Week names
                      "We", "Th",
                      "Fr", "Sa",
                      "Su"),
        day.size = 2.25
        )
```

At this point you should have a calendar for October 2023 with title, weekday names, and the day in the upper left hand corner of each calendar day. However, now I want to add splits to the calendar...vertical, horizontal, or diagonal.

```
# Vertical -------

custom_cal +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0:6,
             color = "grey60")


# Horizontal ------------------

custom_cal + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1:5,
             color = "grey60")
  
  
# Diagonal --------------------

custom_cal + 
  geom_abline(
    intercept = 1:11,
    slope = -1,
    color = "grey60")
```

Is there a way to clip the overlap lines to just the size of the calendar? I want the subdivision, but without overlap for all three calendar types.  If it makes you feel better, this calendar is being used to help keep track of who has fed the dog in the house, AM or PM, and will be signed by whoever performs that task.

Thank you for the help with this! Trying to automate the process as much as possible.  Building this out in excel for a few months was getting quite tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CalendR` produces a ggplot object with a nicely formatted `data` member and an existing aesthetic mapping. You can easily split the days using `geom_segment`

**Diagonal**

```r
custom_cal +
  geom_segment(aes(x = dow - 0.5, xend = dow + 0.5,
                   y = y - 0.5, yend = y + 0.5), col = "gray")
```

[image]

**Horizontal**

```r
custom_cal +
  geom_segment(aes(x = dow - 0.5, xend = dow + 0.5, yend = y), col = "gray")
```

[image]

**Vertical**

```r
custom_cal +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = dow,y = y - 0.5, yend = y + 0.5), col = "gray")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Awesome! this is exactly what I was looking to do....I initially looked at the data to see if there was a way to manipulate the ggplot data, but clearly I missed something.  Great idea and THANK YOU!!!